# Several identical many-to-many relationships with attributes with one entity class for each of the linking tables

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I have an `Email` entity which has `To`, `Cc`, and `Bcc` collections of `Contact` entities. The relationships are many-to-many and I need ordering for the emails in `To`, `Cc` and `Bcc`. So I have to introduce a 3rd entity inbetween - `EmailContactAssignment` with an additional `SortOrder` property.

Now because I have 3 distinct many-to-many relationships here I need 3 of these relationship tables.

The only solution I see at the moment is to have 3 relationship entity classes: `EmailToContactAssignment`, `EmailCcContactAssignment1` and `EmailBccContactAssignmnet`.
It also appears that I cannot have a base class with the navigation properties and empty sub-classes for each of the 3. I'll need to have the same navigation properties duplicated in each of the sub-classes.

Is it possible to still use one entity but have 3 separate many-to-many relationships with this entity for the `To`, `Cc` and `Bcc` relationships?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to still use one entity but have 3 separate many-to-many relationships with this entity for the To, Cc and Bcc relationships?

If they map to separate tables then no it is not possible.

> It also appears that I cannot have a base class with the navigation properties and empty sub-classes for each of the 3. I'll need to have the same navigation properties duplicated in each of the sub-classes.

You could define an interface for the common properties just so you at least have a consistent contract to work with.

```
public interface IContactAssignment
{
    int SortOrder { get; set; }
    ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
}

public class EmailToContactAssignment : IContactAssignment
{
    // ...
}

public class EmailCcContactAssignment : IContactAssignment
{
    // ...
}

public class EmailBccContactAssignment : IContactAssignment
{
    // ...
}
```

And in your DbContext:

```
protected override OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<EmailToContactAssignment>()
        .ToTable("EmailToContactAssignmentXref");

    modelBuilder.Entity<EmailCcContactAssignment>()
        .ToTable("EmailCcContactAssignmentXref");

    modelBuilder.Entity<EmailBccContactAssignment>()
        .ToTable("EmailBccContactAssignmentXref");
}
```